# Angular Chartjs Overlapping Bar Chart with Chartjs ver 2.7

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am trying to write an angular page that will display overlapping bar charts with chartjs ver 2.7. I was following the code at this url

https://jsfiddle.net/17hvoa9t/11/

I found out that it works with chartjs ver 2.5 but I need it to work with Chartjs 2.7

When I used chartjs 2.7, only 1 bar set is overlapping but not the other two. I have been reading the charts.org about barPercentage and categoryPercentage but trying setting them for the two dataset, but it still does not work.

Here is the rendered page

!https://ibb.co/3YLTb2H

Here is my code so far

```
ngOnInit() {
    var data = {
      labels: ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "First",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [10, 20, 30],
        xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
      }, {
        label: "Second",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [5, 30, 35],
        xAxisID: "bar-x-axis2",
      }]
    };

    var options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
          id: "bar-x-axis1",
          barThickness: 30,
          type: 'category',
          categoryPercentage: 0.8,
          barPercentage: 0.9,
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }, {
          display: false,
          stacked: true,
          id: "bar-x-axis2",
          barThickness: 70,
          // these are needed because the bar controller defaults set only the first x axis properties
          type: 'category',
          categoryPercentage: 0.8,
          barPercentage: 0.9,
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: false,
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          },
        }, {
          type: 'category',
          categoryPercentage: 0.8,
          barPercentage: 0.9,
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }

      ]

      }
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });

  }

}


HTML

<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second x-axis will need to have the `offset` set to `true`:

```
{
  display: false,
  stacked: true,
  id: "bar-x-axis2",
  barThickness: 70,
  // these are needed because the bar controller defaults set only the first x axis properties
  type: 'category',
  offset: true, // <-- This property needs added
  categoryPercentage: 0.8,
  barPercentage: 0.9,
  gridLines: {
    offsetGridLines: true
  }
}
```

The chart.js [cartesian axes docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/) state that this defaults to `true`, but that is apparently only for the first axis.

> If true, extra space is added to the both edges and the axis is scaled to fit into the chart area. This is set to `true` for a category scale in a bar chart by default.